# I can't mount my USB drive on my KDE Neon system

Tags: ubuntu, mount, kde-neon

I just logged out and logged back in with another user profile on my **Neon** system.
When I plugged my **flash drive** into my laptop, the file manager didn't see it. I noticed that it was unmounted. I tried to mount it:

```
Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     4096 60538880 60534785 28,9G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
root@pizzawithdirt-voldemort:~# mkdir /media/usb-drive
root@pizzawithdirt-voldemort:~# mount /dev/sda1 /media/usb-drive/
```

But it gave an error.

```
mount: /media/usb-drive: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

How can I **mount** it correctly, without errors?

Comment: Shut down completely and reboot. If the drive still cannot be mounted, its file system is damaged (e.g.,  by interrupting files being written). In that case, try formatting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebooted, formatted all the partitions and it got fixed. still thanks tho.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that mount.vfat is not installed. Check and see if it is installed with "which mount.vfat" or "mount.fat/fat32"

It's likely that it's not installed.